# Refresh Grid Control DevExpress

Tags: c#, datagrid, devexpress

I'm polling a site and updating my datasource (SQLite table).  The table gets updated correctly right after the poll.

An XPCollection is associated with the table and the XPCollection is used as the DataSource for the Grid Control.

My problem is:  the Grid's data is not updated. I must open and close the application to see he new data reflected in the Grid.

I have tried all combinations of removing data source, refreshing datasource, but nothing seems to work.

Below is my code for polling and refreshing the Grid,

```
 private async void WaitForXSeconds()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            // do something after x seconds!
            // Updates the DB with new/modified data
            LoadDailyButton_Click(null, null);

            BestGrid.DataSource = null;

            BestGrid.DataSource = BestCollection;

            string starttime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            CycleResultsListBox.Items.Add("Cycle Started : " + starttime.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is a partial snippet of what my class look like:

```
 public class BestData : XPLiteObject
{
    private int id;

    [Key(true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime gameDate;

    public DateTime GameDate
    {
        get { return gameDate; }
        set
        {
            gameDate = value;
        }
    }

    private string hometeamName;

    public string HomeTeamName
    {
        get { return hometeamName; }
        set
        {
            hometeamName = value;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, this one is causing headaches.

Comment: Did you tried the answer of a similar question on the official DevExpress forums ? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q443034

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call

BestGrid.DataBind(); after BestGrid.DataSource = xxx

```
private async void WaitForXSeconds()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        // do something after x seconds!
        // Updates the DB with new/modified data
        LoadDailyButton_Click(null, null);
        BestGrid.DataSource = null;
        BestGrid.DataSource = BestCollection;
        Bestgrid.DataBind();
        string starttime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        CycleResultsListBox.Items.Add("Cycle Started : " + starttime.ToString());
    }
}
```

Édit 1

```
gridControl1.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            gridView1.Columns.Clear();
            gridControl1.DataSource = null;
            gridControl1.DataSource = <newDataSource>;
        }
        finally
        {
            gridControl1.EndUpdate();
        }
```

For you:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    // do something after x seconds!
    // Updates the DB with new/modified data
    LoadDailyButton_Click(null, null);

    gridControl1.BeginUpdate();

    BestGrid.DataSource = null;
    BestGrid.DataSource = BestCollection;

    gridControl1.EndUpdate();

    string starttime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    CycleResultsListBox.Items.Add("Cycle Started : " + starttime.ToString());
}
```

Comment: There is no "DataBind" method on BestGrid.

Comment: I've tried BestCollection.Reload()  and BestGrid.Refresh().  No change.

Comment: pix, tried your suggestion, it is still not updating the BestGrid with the most current data that is persisted in the DB table. If I close the program and re-launch the program, the data is updated with the latest values. Is there some way to simulate this closing and opening of the program?

Comment: Can you please tell us how do save data ? And how do you read it from the database ? It seems that after your save you do still working with old data in your BestCollection.

Answer (score 0):

The following code has fixed my problem.

```
 private async void WaitForXSeconds()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
            // do something after x seconds!
            // Updates the DB with new/modified data
            LoadDailyButton_Click(null, null);


            gridView2.CollapseAllDetails();
            BestGrid.DataSource = null;
            session1.DropIdentityMap();
            BestCollection.Reload();
            BestGrid.DataSource = BestCollection;

            string starttime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            CycleResultsListBox.Items.Add("Cycle Started : " + starttime.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is the code I use to save the data;

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(xsession.DataLayer))
                    {
                        BestData getSingleRec = new XPCollection<BestData>(uow, CriteriaOperator.Parse("[HomeTeamName]=? AND [GameDate]=?", tempStr5.ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(gameDate))).FirstOrDefault();


                                getSingleRec.awayR = Convert.ToInt16(tempStr7);
                                getSingleRec.homeR = Convert.ToInt16(tempStr8);
                                getSingleRec.awayML = tempStr2;
                                getSingleRec.homeML = tempStr3;


                            getSingleRec.Save();
                            uow.CommitChanges();

                    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I said. Something went wrong with your Bestcollection.
Can you please try code I put in my Edit, and add zour BestCollection.Reload() befor BestGrid.DataSource = BestCollection;

I am not sure that you need to DropIdentityMap if you use the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate method on your grid.

And waht is your gridview2? You did not show any code related to this grid before.

Next time, try to show more things of your code.